# How can I check/debug a .cls file?

Tags: debugging, documentclass-writing

I am editing a `.cls` file in order to customize the output of a particular document.  However, I am occasionally coming up against errors.  Is it possible to check that my `.cls` file is valid (i.e. no hanging "`{`")?  Is there a decent way to debug edits to a `.cls` file?

If possible, please suggest some open source tools available for Windows.

Answer (score 6):

1. `syntonly.sty` is useful for typesetting your file faster and checking if it has syntax errors.

   ```
    \RequirePackage{syntonly}
    \syntaxonly
   ```
2. Use an editor with proper syntax highlighting and parenthesis matching!
3. If all else fails, follow the advice here: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-erroradvice.

Quoting TeX itself: `Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues.`